# Is there a JDK 1.7.0.28 for Weblogic Server 11g?

Tags: java, weblogic, java-7, weblogic11g

Hey one of my client want  an application and their JDK version is 1.7.0.28 and they are using weblogic 10.3.6 version.I want to know is there anyOne providing JDK 1.7.0.28??

Comment: you could ask your client where they got it, but first ask them why ... do they really want a (new) application being held together with out of date technology that is quite vulnerable for security (and other) issues, which are fixed in later versions?

Comment: this might help, not sure though: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/verify-java-sdk-version-shipped-ibm-websphere-application-server-fix-packs

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server 10.3.6 supports Java 7. You should advice your customer to use the last Oracle JDK 7 version (Oracle JDK 1.7.0_261) to run its WebLogic server instances.
As Stultuske said, WebLogic 10.3.6 and JDK 7 are out of date. You may consider using recent versions (14c and Oracle JDK 11)